# Attaching the label to the vector of the image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I have an `images` list that contains the image vector and the relevant label (i.e. class).

```
images.append([np.array(image_array_to_vector),np.array([label])])
```

If I want to read the images in `X` and the labels in `y`, I did the following:

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in images])
y = [i[1] for i in images]
```

I then want to save `X` in a text file as follows:

```
X_to_text_file = np.savetxt('x.txt', X.reshape(np.shape(X)), fmt='%5f')
```

The above works fine. The change I would like to make is attach the label to the vector in `X`, and save that to a text file.

I tried doing this for instance:

```
X = np.array([[i[0],i[1]] for i in images])
```

But, got the following error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%5f %5f')
```

And, when trying to use a dictionary as follows:

```
X = np.array([{i[1]:i[0]} for i in images])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So, yes, how can I attach the label to the vector and save that in a text file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is a little hard to answer this question without knowing how the original data looks like or how you want to retrieve the info from the .txt in the future, but changing the "%5f" format to string "%s" format should solve your issue:

```
X_to_text_file = np.savetxt('x.txt', X.reshape(np.shape(X)), fmt='%s')
```

Comment: You can check this answer for more info, seems to be a problem similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230230/typeerror-mismatch-between-array-dtype-object-and-format-specifier-18e

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. In fact, I need the data to be float, since when I change it to '%s', I get the following in another operation in the code: "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Comment: Regarding the original data, it is a 100x100 image, and the label would be a scalar value

Comment: I see your are adding the labels to an array. It is possible to have several labels for a single image?

Comment: I'm asking because I see your are trying to save an array of type "object" with a %5f format. You have a numpy array of numpy arrays.