# while saving numpy as csv code shows error

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I get an error while saving the following NumPy array as CSV

```
print(stfinal)

['70.6' '68.7' '67.8' '67.0' '68.7' '67.7' '66.9' '71.1' '73.0' '72.7'
 '74.2' '72.9' '74.5' '73.8' '68.5' '67.4' '70.0' '72.5' '72.0' '69.3'
 '65.9' '66.2' '65.8' '68.1' '69.7' '69.9' '70.5' '70.1' '70.0' '70.2'
 '72.4' '60.0' '54.6' '54.4' '48.7' '52.4' '53.4' '58.3' '61.4' '63.4'
 '63.0' '64.8' '65.2' '65.6' '63.5' '58.6' '54.1' '58.6' '60.3' '61.0'
 '56.1' '50.0' '45.0' '44.5' '52.4' '56.5' '56.4' '57.0' '57.4' '55.7'
 '52.9' '53.7' '72.6' '65.0' '65.4' '58.7' '60.1' '64.5' '76.3' '73.2'
 '73.9' '74.5' '75.0' '78.9' '75.8' '72.8' '73.4' '65.9' '70.1' '67.8'
 '70.3' '66.6' '60.9' '53.2' '57.1' '63.2' '65.5' '65.5' '65.7' '67.7'
 '64.6' '60.0' '56.2' '7.5' '5.6' '3.7' '4.0' '4.4' '5.0' '5.5' '6.3'
 '7.7' '6.7' '6.9' '4.5' '5.4' '7.3' '7.5' '6.6' '6.2' '6.1' '6.6' '4.3'
 '3.9' '3.9' '3.9' '4.3' '4.9' '5.6' '6.2' '6.7' '5.9' '4.6' '5.4' '26.9'
 '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9'
 '27.0' '27.0' '27.0' '27.0' '27.1' '27.0' '27.0' '26.9' '27.0' '26.9'
 '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '26.9' '27.0' '27.0' '27.0' '27.0']


  numpy.savetxt(f"{month}{year}.csv",stfinal, delimiter=",")
```

whilesaving it in the above way I get the error
[image]

Comment: Did you read about `fmt` parameter of `savetxt`?  Do you understand what an array's dtype is?

Comment: @hpaulj honestly I don't know what any of those mean,its just my first month into python or any programmnig language

Comment: This should work : `np.savetxt('file.csv', l, delimiter = ', ', fmt = '%s')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230230/typeerror-mismatch-between-array-dtype-object-and-format-specifier-18e)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
i just had to convert all elements into float while storing it in the numpy